# Como tratar o campo value?

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho no meu html um formulário, nele eu tenho um campo descrito dessa forma:

```
<option value="sao-gabriel-da-palha">São Gabriel da Palha</option>
```

No meu banco de dados eu tenho que colocar o valor igual ao `value`, portanto eu queria que o valor viesse diferente, viesse como `São Gabriel da Palha` e não `sao-gabriel-da-palha`.
Alguém sabe me dizer como posso fazer isso?

Aqui está o meu formulário:

```
<h3>O que você esta procurando? Digite aqui:</h3>
        <form class="form-inline" action="busca.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite aqui..." name="palavra">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cidade">Selecione a cidade:</label>
                <select name="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade">
                    <option value="sao-gabriel-da-palha">São Gabriel da Palha</option>
                    <option value="São Domingos do Norte">São Domingos do Norte</option>
                    <option value="Vila Valério">Vila Valério</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: normalmente o value é a chave primária, id, código, o a informação que será exibida, nome, descrição, etc...são duas colunas na tabela do banco. Ps Se você for de São Gabriel da Palha, saudações capixabas, sou de Colatina =]

Comment: Você está utilizando o php?

Comment: Sim, estou usando PHP.. E sim @Rovann Linhalis sou de São Gabriel da Palha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo fazer o que o Rovann Linhalis mencionou em seu comentário, mas caso queira continuar com a ideia, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//Vamos supor que você colocou o valor do option na variável $cidade
$cidade = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $cidade));
```

O código está repondo os hifens por espaços em branco e colocando letra maiúscula no inicial de cada palavra.

Agora é só gravar o valor de `$cidade` no banco de dados.

**Alguns testes:**

```
Entrada: "sao-gabriel-da-palha"    Saída: "Sao Gabriel Da Palha"

Entrada: "rio-de-janeiro"          Saída: "Rio De Janeiro"
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kqeHyW).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Troca 'fromPerson' pelo nome do seu campo html
if( isset($_POST['fromPerson']) && $_POST['fromPerson'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
    $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
    echo $fromPerson;
}
```

Comment: Bacana, não sabia dessa função

Comment: Vejo uma redundância em seu código, caso ele valide `$_POST['fromPerson'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha'`, ele não precisaria validar o `isset($_POST['fromPerson'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Seu formulário é gerado através do PHP ou você tem ele escrito numa página HTML estática?

Se você está gerando o formulário através do PHP é melhor gerá-lo com os valores do jeito que devem ir para o banco de dados...

```
<select>
<?php 
// imaginando que o nome das cidades venham de algum array parecido com este
$cidades = array( 'São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Goiania');
foreach( $cidades as $cidade ){
    echo '<option value"'. $cidade .'">'. $cidade .'</option>
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: meu formulário é gerado em um arquivo PHP

Comment: Tente seguir o exemplo que dei ai, não deve ser muito diferente, você só vai precisar mudar a linha que mostra o nome da cidade no parâmetro 'value' do select.

Comment: Vou colocar meu formulário aqui na pergunta e você me mostra como devo fazer, pode ser?